# firebase displayName and photoURL are not nullable

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am working on angular application using angularFire2. I am trying to update just the user displayName.

documentation bellow states both displayName and photoURL should be nullable and that we should omit the part we dont want to update.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateProfile

When i try to run same code in the sample it gives error. Any idea? 
[image]

Edit:

User object is interface imported from firebase..so no angularfire

```
import { auth, User } from 'firebase/app';
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not in a position to load up and test an old project of mine, but as a debugging step... I'm curious if this is an AngularFire2 problem - meaning the type definitions aren't correct - or if it's something else. As you probably know, AngularFire2 is just a wrapper around the real `Firebase` package - a wrapper that makes it easier to access the Firebase properties and methods in an Angular environment... your helpful popup is in the way a little, but I assume you're using the AngularFire2 Auth module to get the user. ...Too long, comment continued below...

Comment: On the `const user=` line, can you switch it to `var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;` You'll probably need to require/import the firebase and/or firebase/auth packages at the top of the file.... but my thinking is to see if it works with the base Firebase package, if you get the same error... if so, then I might be stumped. On the other hand, if it works with the base Firebase package, then it's probably a type definition error in the AngularFire2 package and I can look into it further. Based on the docs, it looks like you're doing it correctly... I'm leaning towards it being an AF2 issue

Comment: I am using User object from firebase/app

Comment: Hmmm, well that's not the answer I was expecting or hoping for. If you aren't using the AF2 `user` object... then perhaps your instance of the user object is still getting messed with somehow. I'm just guessing at this point, but if I were in your shoes, the next debugging step I'd do would be to avoid referencing your getCurUser() function and instead try calling the `.updateProfile()` method directly from the firebase user... inside your updateUserDisplayName function, instead try something like `firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({ photoUrl: null }).then( function () { ...etc... })`

Comment: @Davvit did you find a solution of this ? currently having same problem on react

Comment: try empty string instead of null    {photoURL: ""}. Let me know if that works. I dont have the project up at the moment. @ugrdursun